# IntelliJIDEA. Драйвер подключения к БД оффлайн

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, драйвер

Имею некий рабочий контур без возможности подключения к интернету. В нем пытаюсь использовать UI идеи для просмотра БД. Экран настройки подключения:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конечно же, кликая по `Download missing driver files`, никакие драйверы не скачиваются.

Когда то я такую проблему уже решал. Помню что можно было скачать драйвер руками(имею возможность занести в контур файлы извне), и куда-то его подложить идее, но вот в этот раз никак не могу найти, куда именно подкладывать драйвер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел кнопку добавления своего драйвера в окне настроек подключения к БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]